# Glance image registration from remote server

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

I am trying to register a image from a server to remote openstack glance installation. Basically I have processed the image locally through a shell script and now want to import it in a glance running on a different system.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to upload the image to Glance:

1. Make sure you have glance-client installed 
   `pip install python-glanceclient`
2. `source openrc` #An openrc file with creds for that remote openstack installation, see [1] for reference
3. `glance image-create --container-format CONTAINER_FORMAT --disk-format DISK_FORMAT --name IMAGE_NAME --file a-path-to-local-image-file --progress` See "glance help image-create" for params description

That's it. The image will be uploaded to remote glance installation over HTTP.
You can list images there via **glance image-list**

[1] http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_clients_openrc_files.html